# Combine different elements of the same list in different R workspaces

Tags: r, list, rdata

For example: Three R workspaces `A.RData`, `B.RData` and `C.RData`.

- In `A.RData`: A list object `list.example <- list(1,2)`
- In `B.RData`: The same name list object `list.example <- list(NULL,NULL,3)`
- In `C.RData`: The same name list object `list.example <- list(NULL,NULL,NULL,4)`

What i want to get in a new workspace is an object `list.new.example` printed as:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]  
[1] 3  

[[4]]  
[1] 4
```

I have tried

```
file.full <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
list.new.example <- list()
for (i in 1:3) {
   load(file.full[i])
list.new.example <- c(list.new.example, list.example)
}
print(list.new.example)
```

but it's not what i wanted. `NULL` is filling. So thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of problem can be solved by loading each file in a separate *environment*. Then it's just a matter of extracting the element named `list.example` from each of them and combine in a list.

```
# Create the data
setwd(tempdir())
list.example <- list(1,2)
save(list.example, file="A.RData")
list.example <- list(NULL,NULL,3)
save(list.example, file="B.RData")
list.example <- list(NULL,NULL,NULL,4)
save(list.example, file="C.RData")

# Load
files <- c("A.RData", "B.RData", "C.RData")
env <- lapply(files, function(f){
    e <- new.env()
    load(f, envir=e)
    e
})

# Tidy up
l <- lapply(env, "[[", "list.example")
l <- unlist(l, recursive=FALSE)
list.new.example <- l[!sapply(l, is.null)]
```

Environments belong to the more advanced features of R that relatively few users are familiar with. They are however quite simple to understand and very useful, just think of them as unordered sets of named objects, that can be manipulated in same ways as an ordinary list. Like this

```
env[[1]]$list.example
env[[1]][["list.example"]]
```

Comment: You're welcome! But if are happy with the answer you should accept it by clicking the tick mark under the vote arrows.

Comment: So sorry, i am a newer. i will learn the regulations of stackoverflow. So thanks