# How to load several RData with a loop?

Tags: r, loops, load, rdata

I want to load several `RData` files into R. The code I use is

```
for(i in 1:100){
    name_i <- paste('path/file_',i,'.RData', sep="")
    load(name_i)
}
```

and I have also tried:

```
for(i in 1:100){
    paste('name_',i,sep='') <- paste('path/file_',i,'.RData', sep="")
    load(name_i)
 }
```

which resulted in this error:

```
object 'name.in' not found
```

What I want is to have each `RData` to be loaded as:

```
name_1
name_2
.
.
.
name_100
```

but this is obviously not working. Can anyone give me a solution.

bests and thanks in advance

Comment: Note that `'path/file_',i,'.RData, sep="") load(name_i)` is colored red in your question - this is the color of a quoted text string in SO markdown. You are missing a closing single quote `'` after `.Rdata`.

Comment: If you have same object names in different .RData, you could also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088212/combine-different-elements-of-the-same-list-in-different-r-workspaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `paste` line is wrong. This

```
paste('name_',i,sep='') <- paste('path/file_',i,'.RData', sep="")
```

should be something like ('m note sure of your exact file name).

```
fname = paste('path/file_',i,'.RData', sep="")
load(fname)
```

It's also worth thing about using `list.files`, so

```
list.files("path/", pattern="*.RData", full.names="TRUE")
```

Then looping through the file names.